# Add query parameters to current url client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm feeling a bit confused, it feels like this should be dead simple. (ASP.NET MVC3)

We have an Action, called "Product/List". 
We also have a textbox on the page, called "Expiry date".
Now, if that is blank, we don't use it, if it's filled in, we select products with expiry date after that.

There's also a button to "update page", according to selected expiry date.

This needs to be added to the query string (or replaced), which seems to be simple;

```
$(button).bind('click', ...
  window.location.href = '@Url.Action(...)?ExpiryDate=' + ExpiryDate;
)
```

It works, but for me, this looks awful, and makes the adding of new parameters really annoying.

We can't use `@Url.Action(..., new { ExpiryDate=... })`, since this needs to be done client side after the textbox is used.

And, furthermore, we *don't* want to use a submit button and a HttpPost action; this is not a post, it is an update of the view (plus it breaks the browser history).

Most likely I'm missing something; what would be the preferred way to do this?

Comment: Client side templating engines are fantastic for this sort of thing. You could have an MVC Ajax form post the request to the server, and the server can respond with some JSON. The client side templating engine (knockout.js, mustache.js, etc) can then bind the results straight back into your main form with the product details (or a hidden input with the querystring parameter you require).

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but I want the proper url, so users can bookmark the page etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your ExpiryDate input in a form (call it expiryDate) and do a form submit on it

You can choose GET or POST as your request VERB in your action method you can have a form collection to inspect for a null expiryDate.

Or use the ParameterBinding in MVC by have a parameter called expiryDate and check if its null. (you may have to make it nullable)

Comment: Okay, let's ignore the NULL-ness, that hasn't been a problem yet. But this actually seems sort of spot-on, just making the form submit as a GET request.

Comment: give it a try and see how you go, remember to mark this as the correct answer if it works. If you need a quick demo, I can flesh out my answer for you.